# Javascript function not called when aspx page is called using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, call

I am dynamically loading user control .ascx file in .aspx page using LoadControl.
In .ascx page I am making ajax call and calling an .aspx page.
Sample code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

("#TestDiv").load("TestPage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr) {

    if (status == "error")
    {
         //some code
    }
    else
    {
         //some code
    }
}
```

});

In TestPage.aspx I want to call 1 javascript code on its page load.
I have written javscript alert in document.ready function in TestPage.aspx
Following is the sample code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

But this javscript alert is not getting called.
Please let me know what is the issue with this javascript code in TestPage.aspx page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rahul Rathi

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error, a missing );
You're also missing the $ before ("#TestDiv")

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#TestDiv").load("TestPage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr) {

    if (status == "error")
    {
         //some code
    }
    else
    {
         //some code
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax but still the javscript code of TestPage.aspx page is not getting called.